# Querying a column that doesn't have a corresponding variable in the class

Tags: java, hibernate

Assume I have a class

```
class MyClass implements Serializable{    

       int x;
       int y; 
       String z;    
}
```

That represents a table that has x, y, z and another column called i.

I tried this query

```
SELECT c.i from MyClass as c where c.gid= 1
```

This returns `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: could not resolve property: i of MyClass.`

So how to solve this using HQL?

Comment: Use SQL instead of HQL. You cannot query on non-mapped variable either by using HQL nor by Hibernate Criteria

Comment: Could you create a getter in `MyClass` for the `i` variable?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to solve this:

1)  add `i` to `MyClass` with appropriate get/set

(or)

2) Write native SQL query.

Comment: Both are not possible. Any other way?

Comment: @M-T-A: AFAIK, no otherway.

Comment: @M-T-A why is not possible to write native sql query or add property?

Answer (score 0):

As error message says, property `i`  is not present in MyClass. Either add this property in MyClass or update hql accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

may i ask if you did not define i in your Class then how did the column come into existence ?
I mean if you altered the table recently by adding column corresponding to i then you ought to keep your Entities in sync too.